# How does poison work in Commander?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

In Commander / EDH players have 40 life. In normal magic 10 poison counters results in a player being eliminated. Is it still 10 poison counters in Commander / EDH?

In Commander / EDH a player is eliminated if they receive 21 commander damage. If the commander does poison damage does this count double toward the poison threshold, or somehow different than normal poison counters?

Comment: When I first got into Magic, my local group had a house rule of 15 poison counters for Commander. Although no-one I know uses this anymore (and no-one I know is evil enough to make an Infect Commander deck), it's still a good idea to agree on a house rule for commander poison. It is a causal format after all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Comprehensive Rules cover Commander rules (903) in about a page. It only lists one additional rule for winning/losing the game.
Yes, 10 poison counters kills you in Commander.
No, poison damage doesn't count double, Commanders that deal poison damage, deal damage as any other poison creature would deal damage.

> 903.13. The Commander variant includes the following specification for winning and losing the game. All other rules for winning and losing the game also apply. (See rule 104.)
>
> 903.13a A player that’s been dealt 21 or more combat damage by the same commander over the
> course of the game loses the game. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.)

Comment: Note that a commander's poison damage also counts as commander damage (this is seldom relevant unless you have a commander gaining and losing Infect).

Comment: Or if your opponent can't gain poison counters. The damage is still dealt, but no poison counters are gained.